# Run-time 438 VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a run-time 438 error with VBA. Could you help me? I'm beginner.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
Dim nwb As Workbook     
Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("G:\worksheet.xlsm")     

    CopyLastRow = nwb.Cells(nwb.Rows.Count, "A").End(x1Up).Row + 1

    Cells(CopyLastRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value     
    Cells(CopyLastRow, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value     
    Cells(CopyLastRow, 3).Value = ComboBox1.Value     
    Cells(CopyLastRow, 4).Value = TextBox3.Value     
    Cells(CopyLastRow, 5).Value = ComboBox2.Value    
    Cells(CopyLastRow, 6).Value = TextBox4.Value     
    Cells(CopyLastRow, 7).Value = TextBox5.Value    
    Unload Me    
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to specify a work**sheet** not workbook for the cells and rows properties here  property here: `nwb.Cells(nwb.Rows.Count, "A")`

Comment: In this case we can guess what line is throwing the error, but when writing a Stack Overflow question, when you report an error it helps if you also report the line which is throwing the error. Similarly, in VBA you get an error *message* and not just an error *number* -- so report what the message says. Strive to make your questions as informative as possible,

Comment: @Rory Done. The error is in line: CopyLastRow = sheet.Cells(nwb.Rows.Count, "A").End(x1Up).Row + 1

Comment: Looks like that might be a one in xlUp not L. Add `Option Explicit` above Sub line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify worksheet of opened workbook. Try below codes.

```
Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim CopyLastRow As Long

Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("D:\TestWorkbook.xlsx")
Set sh = nwb.Worksheets("Sheet1")


    CopyLastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    sh.Cells(CopyLastRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
    sh.Cells(CopyLastRow, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value
    sh.Cells(CopyLastRow, 3).Value = ComboBox1.Value
    sh.Cells(CopyLastRow, 4).Value = TextBox3.Value
    sh.Cells(CopyLastRow, 5).Value = ComboBox2.Value
    sh.Cells(CopyLastRow, 6).Value = TextBox4.Value
    sh.Cells(CopyLastRow, 7).Value = TextBox5.Value
```

Comment: If it works then please mark it as answer (tick mark).